# Trigger on table update is firing for more than the number of rows updated

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012-express

I have a trigger that is supposed to insert a new record into a audit history table (`EmployeeSalaryHistory`) upon the updating of the `Employees` table that the trigger is set to be on ON.

If I do an `UPDATE` on `Employees` where all the rows in the table are updated the trigger is called more times than the number of rows that are being updated.

e.g. if there are three rows in the `Employees` table the `INSERT` happens 9 times.

```
/*This UPDATE will cause the trigger to fire more than the number of rows in the Employees table.*/
UPDATE Employees SET Salary = Salary * 2 

/* supposed to be fired whenever the salary of an employee is updated */
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EmployeesUpdateSalary] ON [dbo].[Employees]
AFTER UPDATE
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO EmployeeSalaryHistory(EmployeeID, NewSalary, OldSalary)
SELECT I.EmployeeID, I.Salary, D.Salary
From inserted I, deleted D
WHERE I.Salary <> D.Salary

END
```

Comment: Maybe post your solution......as an *appended edit* to your original post.......so others can see what you ended up doing in the end.  Keep your original text "in tact" so the original issue is seen clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You essentially have a "cross join" with this query

```
inserted I, deleted D
```

3 x 3

Note, if I run this query...

```
Use Northwind
GO

Select * from
[dbo].[Categories] c1 , [dbo].[Categories] c2
```

I got "x squared" as the number of rows being returned, where x is the # of rows in the [dbo].[Categories] table.

EDIT

Try this

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalaryHistory(EmployeeID, NewSalary, OldSalary)
SELECT I.EmployeeID, I.Salary, D.Salary
From inserted I, deleted D
where I.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID /* relationship */
and
I.Salary <> D.Salary /* filter */
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeSalaryHistory(EmployeeID, NewSalary, OldSalary)
SELECT I.EmployeeID, I.Salary, D.Salary
From inserted I join deleted D on I.EmployeeID = D.EmployeeID /* relationship */
Where
I.Salary <> D.Salary /* filter */
```

To bring it back to the generic example:

```
    Use Northwind
    GO
Select * from
[dbo].[Categories] c1 , [dbo].[Categories] c2
Where c1.CategoryID = c2.CategoryID
```

will have "x rows", not "x squared rows"......

Comment: The cross join was the problem.